# How can I use a 'reverse connection' with windows 7 remote assistance

Tags: windows-7, remote-assistance

Someone requested my assistance on his laptop. We both have windows 7 machines, so I'd like to use the remote assistance, msra.exe utility.

Unfortunately, he is in a restricted university network which neither of us even knows the configuration of. I just can't connect to him and easyconnect does not work either.

On my side this is different, I have a public ip from my isp and can forward ports on my home router as I want. I also have a cygwin ssh daemon which I could use for tunneling.

Now my question is: how can I make the remote assistance work in a simple way, by tunneling or some option I don't know about?

Comment: Did you try [teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx)?

Comment: @DavidPostill I dont want to make my client install unneccessary software. I think there must be a way with the tools that windows already offers. The only exception would be putty for ssh tunneling, as its really lightweight. Its just putty.exe that can be run without installation.

Comment: The customer module does not require installation. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### I dont want to make my client install unneccessary software

No client install is required. [Client Software download](http://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewerQS.exe).

You will need to install the full version ... and wait for his incomming connection ...

---

#### TeamViewer QuickSupport for Windows

> For the instant customer:
>
> TeamViewer QuickSupport
>
> Simple and small customer module, **runs immediately without
>   installation and does not require administrative rights** - optimized
>   for instant support

Source [teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows.aspx)